# How to make the value emitted by Socket on client-side available in global scope?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am listening on client side for a custom event wherein the value 'movieArr' emitted as part of custom event is not getting available in global scope which is referenced by 'movieArr1'. Why 'movieArr1' still prints undefined but movieArr prints the right value?

```
let movieArr1=[];
socket.on('sendMovieList',function(movieArr) {
         console.log('received movielist2'+movieArr.length+':'+Array.isArray(movieArr));
         movieArr1=movieArr;
});
console.log(movieArr1);
```

Comment: please define exactly what needs to happen on that event firing.

Comment: it is available in the global scope (at least in your example above), but the variable `movieArr1` won't hold any actual data until the socket comes through. You are essentially now setting `let movieArr1=[];` and calling `console.log(movieArr1);` immediately after it, since socket.on... is asynchronous.

Comment: one way you can rewrite it- call the function that needs `movieArr` inside socket.on's callback function and pass in `movieArr` as a parameter. If you show the code that needs `movieArr` I can give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like:

```
var movieArr1=[];
socket.on('sendMovieList',function(movieArr) {
         console.log('received movielist2'+movieArr.length+':'+Array.isArray(movieArr));
         movieArr1.push(movieArr);
         console.log(movieArr1)
});
//console.log(movieArr1);
```

Remember, scope of `movieArr` is limited to its functional scope. It's not accessible outside the functional scope it is defined in.
You can populate the local value into a global value like in the above example.
Also, if you check the value of the `[]` after the event has fired you will be able to see the value reflect in global array.

Usage should be like this working example:

```js
let movieArr1=[];
setInterval(function() {
         movieArr1.push(123);
         console.log(movieArr1.toString());
},2000);
```

Comment: I have tried this "movieArr1.push(movieArr);" still the movieArr1 is undefined.

Comment: You are probably accessing the global array before it is updated. Also, variable hoisting works differently for `let` variables.

Comment: I have tried the same code and looks like i am trying to access the global variable before the real value is pushed in it.

Comment: No its still not resolved. When i print movieArr it prints the right value and in the following line when i push movieArr in movieArr1, it ended up to be undefined in the global scope.

Comment: Did you change the declaration to `var` from `let`?

Comment: See the updated answer. It works correctly. Maybe you should add a runnable example for me to debug. Not sure why it's not working for you

Comment: It is not a code issue. Its a timing issue as the sequence of console log , shows that global variable is printed before the socket.on event happens.  Which states the reason behind the issue.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for then?

Comment: I have to restructure my whole code including the socket event-emitter and event-listener to make this work. With initial code (let and movieArr1=movieArr) its working now.

Comment: Frankly, I do not see any question. If you are looking for a way to print only when the event has fired, solution is already there.